# Two submit button in single form handling different functions in php through angular

Tags: php, angularjs

I have 2 submit buttons in a form having separate functions and hit through ng-click. In those functions i am passing data to server using  same php file through `$http`. I have two conditions

1. `if( isset($_GET['criteria']) && isset($_GET['search']) )`
2. `if( isset($_GET['inform']) && isset($_GET['criteria']) && isset($_GET['search']) )`

through these i can try to manage the functionality for two buttons. But it's not working. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please include your form in the question

Comment: Please explain how is it not working, what do you see in the console log etc.

Comment: place ur html form here??

Answer (score 0):

Both of these following conditions

```
if( isset($_GET['criteria']) && isset($_GET['search']) )

if( isset($_GET['inform']) && isset($_GET['criteria']) && isset($_GET['search']) )
```

will be true in this situation

If you get value in these three

```
$_GET['inform'], $_GET['criteria'],$_GET['search']
```

You can modify the first one like this:

```
 if( isset($_GET['criteria']) && isset($_GET['search']) && !isset($_GET['inform']) )
```